# How I can extract ordered questions and answers from a block of plain text

Tags: php, regex, strpos, strlen

Questions are also available for plain text. I want to be able to use PHP, [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). However, because my Regex information is not enough, I tried to do this with the PHP function.

**Example plain text:** *(starting 12th question -> 15. question, here total 4 questions)*

> 12.A 47-year-old man complains of partial loss of his upper teeth. The patient’s medi- cal history states loss of teeth due to trauma
>   sustained 3 months ago. 11 and 12 are lost. 13, 21, and 22 are
>   destroyed by 2/3 and restored with?llings. Occlusion is orthognathic.
>   What denture construction would be optimal for this patient,
>   considering his occupation as a lecturer? A.Porcelain-fused-to-metal
>   dental bridge B.Plastic dental bridge C.Clasp-retained (bugel)
>   removable partial denture with attachments D.Removable partial laminar
>   denture for the upper jaw E.Swaged-soldered metal dental bridge with
>   faceted intermediate part 13.A 7-year-old boy is diagnosed with epi-
>   demic parotitis (mumps). Name the most li- kely complication of this
>   disease: A.Orchitis B.Colitis C.Dermatitis D.Pneumonia
>   E.Cholecystitis14.During preventive examination a 40-year- old man
>   presents with the following changes: marginal gingiva is enlarged,
>   torus-shaped, cyanotic, slightly bleeding when touched wi- th a dental
>   probe; there is no pain. Staining the gums with Lugol’s iodine
>   solution results in light-brown coloring of mucosa. Make the
>   diagnosis: A.Chronic catarrhal gingivitis B.Acute catarrhal gingivitis
>   C.Exacerbation of chronic catarrhal gingivitis D.Chronic hypertrophic
>   gingivitis E.Generalized periodontitis 15.A 4-year-old boy has been
>   diagnosed wi- th acute purulent periostitis of the upper jaw
>   originating from the 64 tooth. Choose the optimal treatment tactics:
>   A.The 64 tooth extraction, periosteotomy, pharmacotherapy B.The 64
>   tooth extraction, anti-in?ammatory pharmacotherapy C.Endodontological
>   treatment of the 64 tooth, anti-in?ammatory pharmacotherapy
>   D.Endodontological treatment of the 64 tooth, periosteotomy
>   E.Periosteotomy, anti-in?ammatory pharmacotherapy

- There's a question number at the beginning of each question.
- Questions usually have 5 or 4 options

**What I did?**

```
 function gettingQuestionAndOptions($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $string = " " . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;

        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }
```

**How do I use it?**

```
if (gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, '?', "A. ")) {

    $parsedQuestion = gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, '', "?");
    $parsedA = gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, 'A. ', "B. ");
    $parsedB = gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, 'B. ', "C. ");
    $parsedC = gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, 'C. ', "D. ");
    $endQuestion = "?";

} else if (gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, ':', "A. ")) {

    $parsedQuestion = gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, '', ":");
    $parsedA = gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, 'A. ', "B. ");
    $parsedB = gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, 'B. ', "C. ");
    $parsedC = gettingQuestionAndOptions($text, 'C. ', "D. ");
    $endQuestion = ":";

} else {
}
```

**Result:**

I tried min. 4 hours but still I'm getting an irregular result. If there are numbers or `A`, `B` in the problem, I get an even worse result.

---

1. How can I do this better? Or where's my fault?
2. Can I get more correct data with Regex?

Comment: If you're always working on the full text, you could likely improve your results by knowing you'll always start with "1." and then the next match will be "2." etc.

Comment: Yes, mostly the first question starts. But the result I get with php is uneven. For example, it takes the middle of the problem or options does not appear. @miken32

Comment: [See this PHP demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/DuHDm) for an idea with regex or [pattern demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lk5L9U/5). What is better, gets more correct data depends on how your input can look like.

Comment: How do I remove the question content and the option (array to string)? @bobblebubble

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text always starts with a number, grouping them should be a simple matter of just keeping track of the current question you're on, and then searching for the next one. This will help reduce false positives.

```
<?php
$data = "12.A 47-year-old man complains of partial loss of his upper teeth. The patient’s medi- cal history states loss of teeth due to trauma sustained 3 months ago. 11 and 12 are lost. 13, 21, and 22 are destroyed by 2/3 and restored with?llings. Occlusion is orthognathic. What denture construction would be optimal for this patient, considering his occupation as a lecturer? A.Porcelain-fused-to-metal dental bridge B.Plastic dental bridge C.Clasp-retained (bugel) removable partial denture with attachments D.Removable partial laminar denture for the upper jaw E.Swaged-soldered metal dental bridge with faceted intermediate part 13.A 7-year-old boy is diagnosed with epi- demic parotitis (mumps). Name the most li- kely complication of this disease: A.Orchitis B.Colitis C.Dermatitis D.Pneumonia E.Cholecystitis14.During preventive examination a 40-year- old man presents with the following changes: marginal gingiva is enlarged, torus-shaped, cyanotic, slightly bleeding when touched wi- th a dental probe; there is no pain. Staining the gums with Lugol’s iodine solution results in light-brown coloring of mucosa. Make the diagnosis: A.Chronic catarrhal gingivitis B.Acute catarrhal gingivitis C.Exacerbation of chronic catarrhal gingivitis D.Chronic hypertrophic gingivitis E.Generalized periodontitis 15.A 4-year-old boy has been diagnosed wi- th acute purulent periostitis of the upper jaw originating from the 64 tooth. Choose the optimal treatment tactics: A.The 64 tooth extraction, periosteotomy, pharmacotherapy B.The 64 tooth extraction, anti-in?ammatory pharmacotherapy C.Endodontological treatment of the 64 tooth, anti-in?ammatory pharmacotherapy D.Endodontological treatment of the 64 tooth, periosteotomy E.Periosteotomy, anti-in?ammatory pharmacotherapy";
$questions = [];
$question_num = 12;
$previous_question_start = 0;
while (true) {
    $question_start = strpos($data, "$question_num.", $previous_question_start);
    $question_end = strpos($data, (++$question_num) . ".", $question_start);
    if ($question_end === false) {
        // no more matches, this is the last question
        $questions[] = substr($data, $question_start);
        break;
    }
    $questions[] = substr($data, $question_start, $question_end - $question_start);
    $previous_question_start = $question_start;
}
```

At this point you have each question in an array element, so search for your answers in each one, using the same technique. We'll save our results into a new array.

```
$questions_answers = [];
$answer_choices = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
foreach ($questions as $q) {
    $qa = [];
    $qa["question"] = substr($q, 0, strpos($q, "$answer_choices[0]."));
    $previous_answer_start = 0;
    foreach ($answer_choices as $i=>$a) {
        $answer_start = strpos($q, $answer_choices[$i]. ".", $previous_answer_start);
        if (empty($answer_choices[$i + 1])) {
            // end of the array, this is the last answer
            $qa["answers"][] = substr($q, $answer_start);
            break;
        }
        $answer_end = strpos($q, $answer_choices[$i + 1] . ".", $answer_start);
        $qa["answers"][] = substr($q, $answer_start, $answer_end - $answer_start);
        $previous_answer_start = $answer_start;
    }
    $questions_answers[] = $qa;
}

print_r($questions_answers);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question] => 12.A 47-year-old man complains of partial loss of his upper teeth. The patient’s medi- cal history states loss of teeth due to trauma sustained 3 months ago. 11 and 12 are lost. 13, 21, and 22 are destroyed by 2/3 and restored with?llings. Occlusion is orthognathic. What denture construction would be optimal for this patient, considering his occupation as a lecturer? 
            [answers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A.Porcelain-fused-to-metal dental bridge 
                    [1] => B.Plastic dental bridge 
                    [2] => C.Clasp-retained (bugel) removable partial denture with attachments 
                    [3] => D.Removable partial laminar denture for the upper jaw 
                    [4] => E.Swaged-soldered metal dental bridge with faceted intermediate part 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question] => 13.A 7-year-old boy is diagnosed with epi- demic parotitis (mumps). Name the most li- kely complication of this disease: 
            [answers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A.Orchitis 
                    [1] => B.Colitis 
                    [2] => C.Dermatitis 
                    [3] => D.Pneumonia 
                    [4] => E.Cholecystitis
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [question] => 14.During preventive examination a 40-year- old man presents with the following changes: marginal gingiva is enlarged, torus-shaped, cyanotic, slightly bleeding when touched wi- th a dental probe; there is no pain. Staining the gums with Lugol’s iodine solution results in light-brown coloring of mucosa. Make the diagnosis: 
            [answers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A.Chronic catarrhal gingivitis 
                    [1] => B.Acute catarrhal gingivitis 
                    [2] => C.Exacerbation of chronic catarrhal gingivitis 
                    [3] => D.Chronic hypertrophic gingivitis 
                    [4] => E.Generalized periodontitis 
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [question] => 15.A 4-year-old boy has been diagnosed wi- th acute purulent periostitis of the upper jaw originating from the 64 tooth. Choose the optimal treatment tactics: 
            [answers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A.The 64 tooth extraction, periosteotomy, pharmacotherapy 
                    [1] => B.The 64 tooth extraction, anti-in?ammatory pharmacotherapy 
                    [2] => C.Endodontological treatment of the 64 tooth, anti-in?ammatory pharmacotherapy 
                    [3] => D.Endodontological treatment of the 64 tooth, periosteotomy 
                    [4] => E.Periosteotomy, anti-in?ammatory pharmacotherapy
                )

        )

)
```

I kept this code pretty unoptimized so it would be easy to understand, but simple string manipulation is a very low-cost computation so it should be fine for everyday use.

As a side note, I notice you're losing characters like "ﬂ" (f/l ligature) and "ﬁ" (f/i ligature.) If you're pulling this information from a database or web page, make sure you're properly dealing with UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Is it possible to print it as a regular string? :) I tried; `$makeJson= json_encode($questions_answers, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
 $toString = json_decode($makeJson);
 foreach ($toString as $ts) {
  echo $ts->answers[1];
 }` but I was not successful.

Comment: How to print question and options in plain text in your code? @miken32

Comment: It's a simple array of strings, you can do whatever you like with it. `foreach ($questions_answers as $q) {echo $q["question"];}`

Comment: Yes but I think I told you wrong. I asked to print the questions separately. I need this to save to the database. Therefore; Is it possible to print separately to the question and options of question? - Every `foreach` operation to be written to the database @miken32

Comment: Is not it possible? I want to save the question and the options of the same problem to the database. So how can I get it? // Can you give only the question and question of the problem as a string? Thank yo @miken32